# How to skip files with ditto command line utility?

Tags: terminal, photos.app, filesystem

I'm trying to import a large (100GB+) iPhoto library located on a seemingly faulty external drive, that always yields an error `-36` when I attempt to copy the library using Finder. I therefore tried the `ditto` the approach suggested in [this article](https://samwize.com/2017/06/26/backing-up-photo-library-and-handling-corrupted-files-error-36/):

```
ditto -v ~/Pictures/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary/ /Volumes/MyDrive/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary/
```

The problem is, when `ditto` reaches the faulty file, I get these errors logged:

> ditto: (...)/MVI_5490.MOV: Device not configured
>
> ditto: (...)/IMG_5489.JPG: No such file or directory

Then suddenly macOS complains about the drive being ejected improperly, and the copy stops.

These two files seem to have contiguous IDs and reside in the same directory. So I guess that they're both located on a single faulty block.

I'd like to try preventing `ditto` from attempting to copy these files altogether, in the hope that this will prevent the disk from failing and allow the copy to complete (I don't care about a couple photos/videos missing, and I can always rebuild the iPhoto library later on).

Is there a way to instruct `ditto` to skip a known list of files?

If not, I'd accept an alternative solution (`cp` command based or any other), as long as it can handle the copy the way `ditto` does it (preserving ownership, permissions and such).

Comment: You can create a list of files that ditto will copy.  Think the find command.    see man ditto  --bom bom     Copy only files, links, devices, and directories that are
                   present in the specified BOM.

Comment: You could try out my beta file copier.  It was write with your situation in mind. I've tested it on a working drive, but not on a problem drive.  See:https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250464381?answerId=250896657022#250896657022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've worked around the problem by booting on the failing drive and copying to the external drive.**

I still get the I/O errors when attempting to read the same files, but at least the drive does not eject (and the system does not crash) so I was able to go through with `ditto` and ignoring/logging files in error.

---

Otherwise, the answer to my original question seems to lie with `rsync`:

```
rsync -av --exclude='path1/to/exclude' --exclude='path2/to/exclude' source destination
```

or:

```
rsync -av --exclude-from=FILE source destination
```

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/333641/284979) for more information.